# Translating Java code into spreadsheet equation

Tags: java, calculation

Java isn't my strong point, so hopefully, someone can explain this short piece of code.

I would like to work out the code and translate it into a Spreadsheet.

The original App was built for use on a Blackberry Phone, we would enter a 4 digit number and a 4 digit result was display and manually put into a spreadsheet.

The guys who originally coded this are no longer working for us and never left any notes, so any assistance would be great.

```
    code = Integer.parseInt(textCode.getString());
    result = 0;
    for (n = 666; n <= 999; n += 2)
    {
    result += code;
    result += result % n;
    result += result / n;
    result %= 10000;
    }
```

Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to put this into a single Excel function.  You'd need at least a macro.

Comment: You cannot easily do loops in excel equations. But you could trivially write a macro.

Comment: There are only 10000 possible results. You could work them all out by running that code in a loop, paste the results into the speadsheet then do a look up of some kind.

Comment: That's probably the easiest option if you want an unmaintainable mess. I suppose if one is using a spreadsheet; that is probably one of your aims...

Comment: Ahh that explains it, so its not a simple 'answer in answer out' equation?

Comment: Do you want to make an Excel macro? or just understand this Java code and get it working? Here's the runnable java code: https://repl.it/MfVm